# What is a good database choice for a JIRA 10-user installation?

Tags: database, jira

I've been working with JIRA and Greenhopper for a few weeks now, and have decided to settle on it as a development aid. That means it's time to stop using the HSQL database.

Loading will be very light; of the 10 users there will only be a maximum of two really active users, interacting intermittently, with state changes on JIRA items at fewer than 100 a day, peak. I have the feeling that supporting this with a SQL Server install would be more than overkill. With SQL Server Express explicitly not supported I have to choose something else.

My question is: *Hosted on a machine as described below, which database, among all those openly supported by Atlassian, would work best? Should I run the DB on the hardware, encase it in a VM of its own, or add it to the existing VM?*

> Hardware: Dual-Core Core 2 processor, 8 GB Memory, mirrored 250 GB
>   hard disk, a third spinning "backup" disk connected internally.
>
> Host OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> VM Host: VMWare Server 2008, currently running one Win Server 2003 R2
>   instance (2 GB memory allocated in the VM, 20 GB virtual disk, running a lightly loaded IIS instance with a few utility web services)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar setup with Confluence and Jira sharing a box. 
For the load you describe my suggestion would be to use PostgreSQL on the local VM. I looked at in terms of building a specific use appliance. It is really a matter of preference.

Comment: I found a Turnkey.org VM which ran postgres and is basically perfect for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: +1 for postgresql.  I've had serious trouble with MySQL and JIRA.

Answer (score 1):

We're using MySQL with JIRA, I recommend that for easier administration than PostgreSQL. Both are good options - if you have more experience with one, use that.

The supported database list is available at:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Supported+Platforms

You should be able to run it on the same vm as your JIRA install. If you have a central MySQL server with scheduled database backup jobs (mysqldump) then I would recommend putting the database there (to take advantage of your pre-existing db backups).

Comment: There's always seemed to me to be an even split between the people who think MySQL is easier, and those who think that about Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Why Atlassian refuses to support MSSQL Express for the 10-user license is beyond me. We run two installations with MSSQL 2008 R2 without any problems at all.

Obviously - pick whatever DB you feel like. Just keep in mind that certain backup solutions (like Backup Exec that we use) doesn't support mysql/postgresql without using third party scripts on the DB server to get snapshots.